# Django JSONField and Q object

Tags: django, django-models

I would need to do something similar:

```
# models.py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField,

class MyModel():
    ***
    **
    admin_fields = JSONField(_('admin fields'), blank=True, null=True, help_text=admin_fields_help_text)


my_instances = MyModel.objects.filter((Q(my_model_id=pk) & 
        Q(children__isnull=True)) & 
       ~Q(admin_fields__status__contains='deleted'))
```

Or

get all records with `id=pk` and `children__isnull=True` and JSONField admin_fields must not contain `status==deleted`

Currently 
    admin_fields = {'status': 'deleted'}

Instead it returns only the record that has

```
admin_fields = {'status': 'deleted'}
```

Is ~Q() not working with JSONField?

Ideas?

Thanks,

D

Comment: Have you tried `MyModel.objects.filter((Q(my_model_id=pk) & 
        Q(children__isnull=True))).exlude(admin_fields__status__contains='deleted')` ? or maybe try the following `MyModel.objects.filter(my_model_id=pk, children__isnull=True).exlude(admin_fields__status__contains='deleted')`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about absolute. It works with a small change: `MyModel.objects.filter(my_model_id=pk, children__isnull=True).exclude(admin_fields__contains={'status': 'deleted'})`. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you intend to do using the `exclude()` method.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(my_model_id=pk, children__isnull=True).exclude(admin_fields__contains={'stat‌​us': 'deleted'})
```